# APT user guide and where can I find it?

Tags: command-line, apt, documentation

I am trying to get hold of the APT user guide to browse some of the more advanced options other than just apt-get etc. however whenever I type
`man apt`I get a message telling me manpage is not loaded. I know the command works as `man sudo` works fine.

I've tried `sudo apt-get install apt-doc` which tells me  `apt-doc is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded`

Is there a local storage area for these manuals or someway I can load it?

Comment: Like: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto ?

Comment: Something 'like' that but with a list of advanced commands. I already use commands such as -assume-yes and -no-act but I know the command can do so much more on the back end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am running natty and the man page is included in the package `apt`

The content of the page is

> > apt(8)
> >     apt(8)
>
> NAME
>          apt - Advanced Package Tool
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          apt
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          APT is a management system for software packages. For normal
>   day to day
>          package management there are several frontends available, such
>   as apti‐
>          tude(8)  for  the  command line or synaptic(8) for the X Window
>   System.
>          Some options are only implemented in apt-get(8) though.
>
> SEE ALSO
>          apt-cache(8),  apt-get(8),  apt.conf(5),  sources.list(5), 
>   apt_prefer‐
>          ences(5), apt-secure(8)
>
> DIAGNOSTICS
>          apt returns zero on normal operation, decimal 100 on error.
>
> BUGS
>          This manpage isn't even started.
>
> ```
>    See  <http://bugs.debian.org/apt>.  If you wish to report a bug
> ```
>
> in apt,
>          please see /usr/share/doc/debian/bug-reporting.txt or the 
>   reportbug(1)
>          command.
>
> AUTHOR
>          apt was written by the APT team .
>
> Debian GNU/Linux                 16 June 1998
>   apt(8)

So basically, if you have the man pages for apt-cache, apt-get, apt.conf, sources.list, apt-prefer-ences and apt-secure, you have the documentation.

See also : [online man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt)

Comment: I don't get that page with `man apt` but `man apt-get` work fine. Now i'm confused but happy that I can now see the links to the other pages so thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The binaries provided by the *apt* package are `apt-config`, `apt-key`, `apt-get`, `apt-cdrom`, `apt-cache`, and `apt-mark`. Each command has its own manpage that you can get for example with `man apt-get`. In addition, further man pages describe archive authentification (`man apt-secure`) and the preferences (`man apt_preferences`).

The package *apt-doc* only provides the user guide in several languages (which you can find in `/usr/share/doc/apt-doc`), it does not offer much information for advanced usage.

Comment: Thank you. I have upvoted for you as I can not mark both as answers to my question.